# Pop up in New Window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, target

I have the following line of code that I'm having trouble popping up in a new window because the target wants to only focus on the URL which isn't the valid content:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/job/orgtools/ltilaunch/jobLtiLaunch.js"></script>
</head><body>
<p><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000080;"> <a href="#" onclick="javascript:lti_launch( {'handler_urn':'job/lti/job_mstr', 'skip_parent_check':'true','targetId':'assess'} );"><span style="color: #000080;">Assess</span></a> </span></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000080;"><a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:lti_launch( {'handler_urn':'job/lti/job_mstr', 'skip_parent_check':'true','targetId':'grade'} );"><span style="color: #000080;">Grade</span></a> </span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a framework that launch popup? we don't know how work lti_lauch. Maybe if you look under /job/orgtools/ltilaunch/jobLtiLaunch.js you can found a solution. Regards.

Comment: -1 It's not clear at all what the actual problem is. Please add some information

Comment: Basically, this simply a list of links that render content via javascript launch within frames. When user clicks on each link we would like it to pop up in a new window, however added simple target="blank" code pops up the list of links in a new window, and the javascript launch still displays in frames. LTI is a method to display proxy based services within external systems. Sorry, not sure if this helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: I tried that with both the target="_blank" and without, and unfortunately that didn't seem to work.